# Support for the experimental syntax 'optionalChainingAssign' isn't currently enabled

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am getting this error in my react js application. I'm not using Eslint in my app and I configured babel with default settings.

In my package.json I have these settings configured

```
"dependencies": {
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.5.1",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.1",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
"@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^2.10.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"react-slick": "^0.30.1",
"react-textarea-autosize": "^8.5.3",
"slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build && build-script.bat",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "development": [
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
  ]
}
```

I also configured .babelrc file with

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

If anyone encountered with same issue and know it's solution then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below babel plugin to parse and transform the syntax. This is suggested if your target browsers will not have the support for this feature

```js
{
   ...,
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining-assign"]
}
```